# Get form parameters from multipart request without getting the files

Tags: java, servlets, multipartform-data

I'm looking for a way to get the form parameters of a HTTP multi-part request in a Servlet-filter without uploading files (yet).

request.getParameterMap() returns empty. I understand this is because of the request being multi-part.

I've looked at commons.HttpFileUpload but this seems to be overkill for my situation. In this filter I'm only interested in the normal parameters, and don't want to handle the file-upload yet.

Edit: the main problem is that I need to have an intact HttpRequestObject further down the filter stack. The HttpFileUpload seems to consume part of the request data (probably by using the data stream object and closing it again.)

Comment: Quote: "i need to have an intact HttpRequestObject further down the filter stack": why and what for?

Comment: because i am working on a fairly large existing project which relies on having the HttpRequest object, which i cant easily change.

Comment: That's too little information. Even without commons fileupload you'd have the same problem. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly not overkill, it's the right way and always better than writing the parser yourself. The [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) is developed and maintained for years and has proven its robustness in handling multipart/form-data requests. You don't want to reinvent the wheel. If you really want to do it (I don't recommend it), then read on the [multipart/form-data specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html) and start with reading the `HttpServletRequest#getInputStream()` (warning: this is a mix of binary and character data!).

You can if necessary also write a Filter which makes use of Apache Commons FileUpload under the hood and checks every request if it is multipart/form-data and if so, then put the parameters back in the request parameter map with help of Commons FileUpload and put the uploaded files (or exceptions) as request attributes, so that it's finally a bit more transparently in your servlet code. You can find [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/11/multipartfilter.html) a basic example to get the idea.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the answers already provided - I had a very similar problem in that I was trying to add some CSRF validation to our existing web app. We decided to include a special token in each form using some JS and add a servlet filter to check that the token existed (therefore a generic, isolated solution).

The servlet would check if the token was present but broke for every form that provided a file upload option. Hence I landed at this page frequently while doing some googling.

The work around we used (while attempting to avoid any dealings with the uploaded files) was to get some JavaScript to add the token as a GET parameter, i.e. We modified the form's action URL to include the token and therefore could use the HttpServletRequest.getParameter() method for the token (and only the token).

I have tested this in IE, FF and Chrome and all seem to be happy.

Hope this helps anyone who also finds themselves in a similar situation.

Comment: just ran into this exact scenario. Adding csrf token as a get param did the trick

Comment: problem with this approach is that the token stays in the URL so https can not protect it http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-include-csrf-token-in-action

Answer (score 4):

The [Oreilly Servlets](http://www.servlets.com/cos/) website has some sample code which you can download customise and use. This includes [MultipartRequest](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html) which sounds like it does what you require, it un-boxes a multipart request and allows access to the parameters and the files separately.

Comment: The c.o.s.MultipartRequest is a well known class indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Commons FileUpload provides a mechanism to read request params from a multipart form upload.

There's a really great example of how to grab the request parameters here:

[How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)