# how to pass text value along with multiple file upload form

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I am having one file upload form which uploads multiple files.
Right now I have hard coded the folder name in which the uploaded file is to be stored.

But what I need is at the time of upload the form should also send folder name which will be created on the server to store uploaded files.

This is my form

```
 <form action="uploadprocess.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
<input name="file" type="file" id="file">
<input name="file" type="file" id="file">

<input name="foldername" type="hidden"> <!-- i will set folder name during run time -->
</form>
```

I am getting null when I use `request.getParameter("foldername")`

Comment: Try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144657/fileupload-jsp-cannot-pass-additional-form-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. To get value from a form of "multipart/form-data" you need to use `MultipartRequest`.When you use multipart form you can access parameters on `request` object.

See this: [get-form-parameters-from-multipart-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748259/get-form-parameters-from-multipart-request-without-getting-the-files) to know how to get parameter in multipart request.

Else try this:

1. download http://www.servlets.com/cos/index.html
2. invoke `getParameters()` on `com.oreilly.servlet.MultipartRequest`