# fileupload jsp cannot pass additional form attributes

Tags: jsp

I have the following in jsp:

```
<form action="/ucReady2/uploadservlet" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="filename_1">File: </label> <input class="wfs_button"
            id="filename_1" type="file" name="filename_1" size="50" /> <input
            type="input" name="rowindex" value="<%=rowIndexObj%>" /><input
            class="wfs_button" type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

In the uploadservlet, I have:

```
String attribute = request.getParameter("rowindex");
```

the attribute is always null !. The input field itself has a value before I submit the form. The servlet cannot read this value.

Comment: If I remove enctype then I am able to pass rowindex. How can I use fileUpload and still pass a variable to the servlet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay. I found the solution from fileupload website:

```
if (item.isFormField()) {
  if ("rowindex".equalsIgnoreCase(item.getFieldName())) {
     attribute = item.getString();
   }
}
```