# how to get values from a multipart request in java

Tags: java, html, servlets

Here is the form submission part

```
var form=document.forms["mainForm"];
form.setAttribute("action",url_action);
form.setAttribute("method","post");
form.setAttribute("enctype","multipart/form-data");
form.setAttribute("encoding","multipart/form-data");
form.submit();
```

Now how can I get all the parameters or form input type names and corresponding values to a map in servlet?

Map example:

```
name=Abhishek
age=25
filename=abc.txt
```

Comment: Missed multi part : Duplicates this  somehow :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748259/get-form-parameters-from-multipart-request-without-getting-the-files

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Commons / FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/):

> **The simplest case** The simplest usage scenario is the following:
>   Uploaded items should be retained in
>   memory as long as they are reasonably
>   small. Larger items should be written
>   to a temporary file on disk. Very
>   large upload requests should not be
>   permitted. The built-in defaults for
>   the maximum size of an item to be
>   retained in memory, the maximum
>   permitted size of an upload request,
>   and the location of temporary files
>   are acceptable. Handling a request in
>   this scenario couldn't be much
>   simpler:

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

**Source:** [Using FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html)