# How to retrieve String on Servlet send as a part of Multipart Post

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

This may be very simple question but I have been looking around for a while.
I am sending two strings to a Java Servlet on Tomcat 7.

```
multipartContent.addPart("destadd", sb1);
multipartContent.addPart("destfilename", sb2);
```

I am trying to retrieve these String like this

```
String destFileName = request.getPart("destfilename").getName();
```

but in vein. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was running around for two days almost, fianlly I got the answer

```
Part destFileNamePart = request.getPart("destfilename");
Scanner s = new Scanner(destFileNamePart.getInputStream());
String destFileName = s.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i had exactly the same situation 

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late but it may help for someone else:

```
IOUtils.toString( destFileNamePart.getInputStream() );
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks, i assume this more optimized than using the scanner ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Get form parameters from multipart request without getting the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748259/get-form-parameters-from-multipart-request-without-getting-the-files).

You can also use utility class such as [O'Reilly MultipartRequest](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html) and more info [here](http://www.servlets.com/cos/)

Comment: A code in the answer would surly have got an upvote and accepted answer.

Comment: Don't use O'Reilly MultipartRequest. It's older than your grandfather. Use Apache Commons FileUpload.