# Retrieving radio button in Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, null

I am using `Servlet`. And `request.getParameter()` always returns null value even if the radio buttons are checked. Can anyone help?

This is my `index.jsp` page

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="FileLoader" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="se" value="pre-signing" checked = "checked">
Pre-signing </label>
<br>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="se" value="post-signing">
Post-signing </label>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This my servlet page

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response)throws  ServletException, java.io.IOException {
String radioButton= request.getParameter("se");
System.out.println("radioButton ::"+radioButton);}
```

It returns me a null value even if the radio buttons are checked.

Comment: Why have you enclosed `<input type...>` inside a `<label>` tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2424824/157882)

Comment: @Rohit: it will put focus on radio button if you click on label text.

Comment: @BalusC.. Oh! I thought surrounding it with <label> tag is possible reason that the value of radio button is not sent. Didn't knew that. :)

Comment: @BalusC.. I'm learning to work with Java EE 6, and I must say that your answers and blog are so much helpful, and I got to know things, that I can't get anywhere else. You're awesome. Cheers :)

Comment: @BalusC The question really doesn't sound as a duplicate of [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/). Maybe the answer is the same, though.

Comment: @BalusC Both these questions are poorly asked, when we see the answer...

Comment: @Rohit : is that wrong? I am new to this.. Can you help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since your encoding type is multipart.. your http request will not contain the information you need.

it will be available in the [MultiPartRequest](http://www.servlets.com/cos/javadoc/com/oreilly/servlet/MultipartRequest.html).. 
see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748259/get-form-parameters-from-multipart-request-without-getting-the-files).. it will help

Comment: O'Reilly `MultipartRequest` is prehistoric and is known to have some peculiar bugs (e.g. encoding). I really wouldn't recommend it nowadays.